# Confused about ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core model state

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core in general. I'm building a little web app to try to become familiar with these. I'm confused about a few things. Please see the code below as reference.

I'm using `CreateTest.cshtml` to add a new `CrmInvoice`.  My first attempt, on debugging, in OnGet and OnPost I see that

```
CrmInvoice.Id = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
```

I assume this is what EF does because Id is required and it's a guid.  I thought EF would generate a new guid as I've seen when testing a create client page, where if I don't have an Id user input, EF knows on post to assign a new guid to the client it is saving, but in that case (with the create client page) I'm not doing anything with the client model in the OnGet method as I am here with the invoice model where I am trying to set up the select lists.  But regardless, to deal with this, I added this line to the OnPost method

```
CrmInvoice.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

which manually assigns the guid at the start of my OnPost method.  **Q1**: Why do I have to do this?  Shouldn't EF know to assign a new guid for this invoice?  Is this caused by me getting a new `CrmInvoice` in my OnGet because I'm tring to set up the select lists?

**Update**: I thought this was a problem, but it is not.  I think this is intended behavior, the invoice is saved with a new guid by EF.  EF must use the zeros to represent a null guid.  In case anyone is interested.

---

In OnPost of CreatTest.cshtml, the model state is invalid, specifically the `CrmClient` and `InvoiceType` show as invalid as they are null.  I thought EF would recognize that this is a new invoice and the relationship to `CrmClient` and `InvoiceType` based on the `ClientId` and `InvoiceId` automatically.

[image]

Attempting to deal with this, I tried adding this code to the beginning of the OnPost

```
    CrmInvoice.InvoiceType = await _context.CrmInvoiceTypes
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(it => it.Id == CrmInvoice.InvoiceTypeId);
    CrmInvoice.Client = await _context.CrmClients
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == CrmInvoice.ClientId);
```

but EF still complained, saying the `CrmClient` and `InvoiceType` were invalid even though they now contained the correct entities.  **Q2**: Why does this not work?

Finally, I commented out the code above and changed my `CrmInvoice` class so that Client and InvoiceType aren't necessary

```
    public virtual CrmClient? Client { get; set; } // Can be null
    public virtual CrmInvoiceType? InvoiceType { get; set; } // Can be null
```

but I feel like this is not the right approach since I created the tables in SQL first with the appropriate relationships and ran Scaffold-DBContext to get my models, so you'd think the models would be correct and not need this modification.  This allowed me to proceed, of course EF didn't complain anymore about the model state.  **Q3**: Was this the right approach?  Or is there something I'm not understanding / do I need to build the relationships and load the related models in a different way?

Thank you for your consideration.

`CreateTest.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model Admin.Web.Pages.Invoices.CreateTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Invoice for " + Model.ClientName;
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>CrmInvoice</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <!-- Leave out Invoice Id input - expecting EF to generate -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CrmInvoice.ClientId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CrmInvoice.ClientId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ClientId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CrmInvoice.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CrmInvoice.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CrmInvoice.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CrmInvoice.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CrmInvoice.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CrmInvoice.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CrmInvoice.InvoiceTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="CrmInvoice.InvoiceTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.InvoiceTypeId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

`CreateTest.cshtml.cs`:

```
using AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace Admin.Web.Pages.Invoices
{
    public class CreateTestModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models.AppDbContext _context;

        public CreateTestModel(AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models.AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public CrmInvoice CrmInvoice { get; set; } = new CrmInvoice();

        public string ClientName { get; set; } = "Default Client";

        public IActionResult OnGet(Guid? clientId)
        {
            if (clientId == null || _context.CrmClients == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Clients/Index");
            }

            var client = _context.CrmClients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == clientId);

            if (client == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Clients/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientName = client.Name;
                CrmInvoice.ClientId = clientId.Value;

                ViewData["ClientId"] = new SelectList(_context.CrmClients, "Id", "Name", clientId);
                ViewData["InvoiceTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.CrmInvoiceTypes, "Id", "Description");

                return Page();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            //Don't need to do this
            //CrmInvoice.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            //CrmInvoice.InvoiceType = await _context.CrmInvoiceTypes
            //    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(it => it.Id == CrmInvoice.InvoiceTypeId);
            //CrmInvoice.Client = await _context.CrmClients
            //    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == CrmInvoice.ClientId);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.CrmInvoices == null || CrmInvoice == null)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.CrmInvoices.Add(CrmInvoice);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

`CrmInvoice.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models;

public partial class CrmInvoice
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public Guid InvoiceTypeId { get; set; }

    //public virtual CrmClient Client { get; set; } = null!; // Cannot be null
    public virtual CrmClient? Client { get; set; } // Can be null

    public virtual ICollection<CrmLineItem> CrmLineItems { get; set; } = new List<CrmLineItem>();

    //public virtual CrmInvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; } = null!; // Cannot be null
    public virtual CrmInvoiceType? InvoiceType { get; set; } // Can be null
}
```

`AppDbContext.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models;

public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CrmClient> CrmClients { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CrmInvoice> CrmInvoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CrmInvoiceType> CrmInvoiceTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CrmLineItem> CrmLineItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CrmLineItemType> CrmLineItemTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CrmClient>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_CrmClients_Id");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.QlId, "UQ__CrmClien__F620188972340536").IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Address1)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Address2)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Address3)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Attn1)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Attn2)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Note1)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Note2)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.QlId)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrmInvoice>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_CrmInvoices_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Client).WithMany(p => p.CrmInvoices)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ClientId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CrmInvoices_CrmClients");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.InvoiceType).WithMany(p => p.CrmInvoices)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.InvoiceTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CrmInvoices_CrmInvoiceTypes");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrmInvoiceType>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_CrmInvoiceTypes_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrmLineItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_CrmLineItems_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Active)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
            entity.Property(e => e.CuSurveyId)
                .HasMaxLength(10)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.Deleted).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.ItemDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Invoice).WithMany(p => p.CrmLineItems)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.InvoiceId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CrmLineItems_CrmInvoices");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.LineItemType).WithMany(p => p.CrmLineItems)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.LineItemTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_CrmLineItems_CrmLineItemTypes");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CrmLineItemType>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_CrmLineItemTypes_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

`CrmClient.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models;

public partial class CrmClient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string QlId { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Attn1 { get; set; }
    public string? Attn2 { get; set; }

    public string? Address1 { get; set; }
    public string? Address2 { get; set; }
    public string? Address3 { get; set; }

    public string? Note1 { get; set; }
    public string? Note2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CrmInvoice> CrmInvoices { get; set; } = new List<CrmInvoice>();
}
```

`CrmInvoiceType.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AspNetCoreWebAppWithAuthMip.Models;

public partial class CrmInvoiceType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<CrmInvoice> CrmInvoices { get; set; } = new List<CrmInvoice>();
}
```

Comment: 1. You have configured entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever()

Comment: 2. You have configured entity.HasOne(d => d.Client). So there should be one client related to invoice. If your invoice can be without related client use HasOptional

Comment: Thank you. I understand about ValueGeneratedNever() but disabling this doesn't seem to change anything, and I didn't need to do this for CrmClient and it works fine. When submitting after this change to test regardless, the guid is still "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}". Also, HasOptional doesn't seem to be an option in EF core, this article stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/… I think says that I need to use IsRequired(false), is that correct?

Comment: 1. Try changing it to entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")

Comment: 2. Try to mark foreign key that should be optional as nullabele, for instance, public Guid? ClientId { get; set; }

Comment: Thank you. I guess I don't understand why your #1 suggestion might be necessary, and I'd really like to understand what's going on rather than just implementing it. I didn't need to do such a thing for CrmClient and my Create page there and it works fine. I have a page that adds the CrmClient and it assigns a new guid automatically if it's not passed in the form. #2 This worked and I'm wondering is this how it should have been to begin with (best practice)? I'm mainly concerned that these are bandages because I'm not doing something correctly to start / I'm not understanding the root causes.

Comment: Could you please be specific what you are trying to achieve? What issue you are having now?

Comment: I think this has something to do with what I'm reading regarding model binding and state. If CrmInvoice.Client and CrmInvoice.InvoiceType are required, in OnPostAsync the model state is invalid, and setting the Client and InvoiceType to valid entities does not change the model state. It seems model state is not something that can be refreshed or updated based on changes you make to correct the validity issues. In other words, once model state is invalid at the beginning of OnPostAsync, it doesn't change regardless of what you do. Does that align with others' understanding of model state?